# how to keep state component instance when changed route in angular

Tags: angular

I have a angular project and using inside a component a lot of  dynamically instance of other components.when changed router do not remove instance.

Comment: you should explain the issue more, add some code or something.

I believe the answer could be to use services to hold the dynamic data/instances but  I need more details about issue to be sure how can I help you

Comment: Can you please add more details or stackblitz link?

Comment: @MaciejWójcik -  public CreateInstance():void
  {
    const factory = this.factory.resolveComponentFactory(AppComponent);
    const componentRef = this.vc.createComponent(factory);
    (componentRef.instance).textToDisplay = "";
}

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using RxJS BehaviorSubject. You can also use a regular RxJS Subject for sharing data via the service. Please go through the shared link.

https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Comment: Tank You. but I using lots of instance of child component in parent component when route change to other component and back to current component instance of child component is not here.

Comment: Can you share your code snippet with "fiddle" or "stackblitz"